# Android Facebook sdk 4 Handle incoming app invite

Tags: android, facebook, broadcastreceiver, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I created an app invite according to [Facebook App Invite](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android) and went through the [App Links Hosting API](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host).

I sent the app invite with success and the receiver side received the app invite notification, however i am not succeeding to handle the incoming invite intent at the receiver side.

I added a BroadcastReceiver to catch the incoming app invite intent

```
   `<receiver
        android:name="com.example.myapp.FacebookAppInviteReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="com.example.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>`
```

but it is never called.

In the "App Links Hosting API", what should be in the "URL" line?

What should be the scheme in the intent filter?

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be adding a broadcast receiver, that intent filter should be added to an activity that can be launched. The Facebook app will create an intent with your custom URL as the "data" field, and will call startActivity with it, so the receiving side (your app) needs to declare an activity.

Comment: Would you care to write a code example on how to create that Intent?